# Group by a count() clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will return a list of aggregated values; however, I want to group the query by one of the aggregated values (a count):

```
select t.Field1, count(distinct(t.Field2), SUM(t.Value1)
from MyTable t
group by t.Field1, count(t.Field2)
```

I've tried putting the count into a subquery, and putting the whole query into a subquery and grouping there.  Is there an way to do this that doesn't involve creating a temporary table (I don't have anything against temporary tables per se).

The desired outcome would look like this:

```
Field1    Count      Sum
----------------------------------------------------    
CAT1      3          19.5
CAT1      2          100
CAT2      2          62
```

The data that I'm working with looks like this:

```
Field1    Field2    Field3    Value1
-----------------------------------------------------
CAT1      1         1         5
CAT1      2         1         2.5
CAT1      3         1         12
CAT1      4         2         50
CAT1      5         2         50
CAT2      6         3         50
CAT2      7         3         12
```

So, I want a grouping by the number of distinct Field2 values per Field3

Comment: sorry, I don't get how are you grouping `Field1` that gets you 2 results for your data set

Comment: the values in sum column are not possible with data you provided, they should be 5, 15, 50, 12...so how did you come up with that?

Comment: @MladenOršolić yeah, the sample data and the desired results don't match at all

Comment: Sorry - I was simply using the numbers for the purposes of illustration.  I've changed the figures so that they add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then the follow should work.

```
select Field1 , Count , Sum(Value1)
from
(
    select t.Field1, count(*) as Count, SUM(t.Value1) as Value1
    from MyTable t
    group by t.Field1, t.Field3

)
as t2 
group by Field1, Count
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I had actually tried this, but I only did the inner sum!